# How do I get a GtkComboBox(Text) to hexpand within a GtkToolItem?

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to embed a GtkComboBoxText in a GtkToolbar (think URL entry) through a GtkToolItem.  It's the most important part of the toolbar, so I'd like it to take as much space as is available.

I've tried setting `hexpand` to true at many various levels of the container chain, from toolbar to GtkComboBoxText (example below) to embedded GtkEntry and GtkCellAreaBox though every intermediate container I could find a handle to.

Highlighting with the inspector, it looks like the toolbar is ok with taking all the horizontal space, but not the toolitem, no matter what it contains.  But that's guesswork.

(my code's Haskell, gi-gtk-3.0.37, dynamically linked to gtk3.22.30, but I don't suppose that changes anything)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  Gtk.init Nothing
  win <- new Gtk.Window [ #title := "win" ]
  on win #destroy Gtk.mainQuit
  vbox <- new Gtk.Box [ #orientation := Gtk.OrientationVertical ]
  #add win vbox

  hbox <- new Gtk.Box [ #orientation := Gtk.OrientationHorizontal ]
  #add vbox hbox
  f1 <- new Gtk.Label [ #label := "filler 1" ]
  #add hbox f1
  cb1 <- new Gtk.ComboBoxText [ #hexpand := True ]
  #add hbox cb1
  f2 <- new Gtk.Label [ #label := "filler 2" ]
  #add hbox f2

  tb <- new Gtk.Toolbar []
  #add vbox tb
  f3 <- new Gtk.ToolButton [ #label := "filler 3" ]
  #add tb f3
  tbi <- new Gtk.ToolItem [ #hexpand := True ]
  #add tb tbi
  cb2 <- new Gtk.ComboBoxText [ #hexpand := True ]
  #add tbi cb2
  f4 <- new Gtk.ToolButton [ #label := "filler 4" ]
  #add tb f4

  #showAll win
  Gtk.main
```

I'm aiming for results similar between the hbox (above) and the toolbar (below).

[image]

Is this kind of behavior possible?  Am I using GtkToolbar wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using `pack_start` (or whatever the Haskell equivalent is) instead of `add`? Or is it even an option?

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I haven't… yet. But `pack_start` appears to be a method of GtkBox; which GtkBox or descendant should I apply it on?

Comment: Judging by your code (I don't know Haskell), you would want to switch to `pack_start` for everything you put in `tb`. So that might look like `#pack_start tb f3 True False 3` or something, since in Python `pack_start` takes 4 arguments: `child`, `expand`, `fill`, and `padding`.

Comment: But `tb` is a `GtkToolbar`… it's a descendant of `GObject`, `GInitiallyUnowned`, `GtkWidget`, and `GtkContainer`, but not `GtkBox`.

Comment: Oh. Then maybe you should put a `GtkBox` inside `tb`, although that might not work. By the way, what is `tbi`?

Comment: `tbi` is the intermediate `GtkToolItem` I instantiate as a container to be able to embed a non-`GtkToolButton` in a `tkToolbar`. I should probably have named it `ti`.

Splicing a `GtkBox` in is a good idea, but it's what I'm simplifying from: my real-world case groups a label and a comboboxtext in an hbox in a toolitem in the toolbar. I've tried multiple places to insert `hexpand`s, to no avail.
I do have to try to `packStart` *those*, who knows!